# Configure server to start on power restore

Tags: ups

I have a UPS which is configured to shut down my server when power goes off, and turn off the UPS a minute after. The server is an industrial pc Advantech ARK-2151. It has 2 BIOS options for Restore AC Power Loss: power on, and "last state".

My problems are the following:

- If I set "last state" the PC wont turn on when the power is restored and the UPS turns on.
- If I set "power on" the PC will start up again as soon as it shuts down, which will make the UPS turn all power down in the middle of booting up or after windows has started.

How can I correctly configure the PC to turn off properly when the UPS sends it's signal, and turn on again only when the UPS power is restored?

UPS brand is Hunnox model HNX 850.

Comment: "power on" should be the right setting. Is there a BIOS update available for the pc?

Comment: I couldn't find any BIOS update. How can I prevent PC to turn on immediatelly after it turns off when using the `power on` setting?

Comment: Does this also happen when you shut down the pc regulary (without the UPS software)?

Comment: Power on is what you want. It's doesn't mean always stay on, it means if it loses and regains ac power it will come back on. You can usually set a delay as well so it doesn't come right back up in the case of multiple blackouts

Comment: @marsh-wiggle yes

Comment: @HarrisonGibbs I couldn't find that delay configuration. I found `slp_s4 assertion width` not sure if that's what I want, anyway the maximum setting was 5 seconds which is not enough

Comment: @HarrisonGibbs I found a setting that delays the boot for X seconds. It just stays in the boot screen halted until the time passes. Could any damage be done by losing power in this screen? This could work for me.

Comment: @vallo that's what you want. That way it doesn't cause os corruption if the power comes back on and shuts off again right away.